# custom attribute to redirect based user object property (asp.net mvc)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I was using a custom authorize attribute, to restrict users without subscription from accessing some actions

```
public class IsSubscriptionActive : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
       //check if user logged in , if not return false
       //get user object from request
       if(UserObject.IsSubscriptionActive)
           return true;
       else
           return false;
    }
}
```

The problem here is that doing this redirects users to login page regardless of whether the user is logged in or not.

So, I want to use the default authorize attribute as it is, but have another attribute which will check for subscription status and redirect.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not tested but try it out:

```
public class IsSubscribedAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity == null || 
              !filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
             filterContext.Result = 
              new RedirectResult(System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.LoginUrl
                           + "?returnUrl=" + 
              filterContext.HttpContext.Server.UrlEncode
                           (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.RawUrl));
        }
        if (isSubscribed)//check subscription here.
        {
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 401;
            filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
        }//you can set the statuscode/result as you like?
    }
}
```

Comment: This code as it is, redirects to login page. where can I set the  custom redirect action or url?

Comment: please dont mind my ignorance about the ActionFilterAttribute class. Is it possible to do somthing like , if(!isSubscribed) //redirect. That is what i cam looking for

Comment: ok i got it. this is my code now 
if (user.IsSubscriptionActive)
            {
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("/Account/Subscribe");}. is this ok, anything needs to be changed?